# ListBox Selected Item

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I am developing a wpf app. I have a database like this.
I have three columns(id,name,profession).listbox shows name column.
 When the user clicks the item in listbox, i wanna show his/her profession 
in textblock.
listbox works well. I have bounded it to a dataview. but how can i show his/her profession in textblock?

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

{

 //What can I write here?

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should proably just bind the text attribute of the TextBlock to the selected item of the list box.  [Check this article at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx)

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Width="248" Height="24" Text="Colors:" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbColor" Width="248" Height="56">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Blue"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Green"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Red"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Purple"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Orange"/>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock Width="248" Height="24" Text="You selected color:" />
    <TextBlock Width="248" Height="24">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding ElementName="lbColor" Path="SelectedItem.Content"/>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: no not like that! listbox shows names. but i wanna show professions in textblock. 
for an example;
listbox shows David Beckham. When the user clicks David Bekcham. 
tetxblock must show  a footballer.

Comment: Yes, like this. All you have to do is tell it the path to the item.
{Binding ElementName="myListBox" Path="SelectedItem.Profession"}

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public DataView view;
        public DataSet ds;
        public Window1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            BindData();


        }


        public void BindData() {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Information.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
            con.Open();
            string sql = "Select * from Dictionary";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {

                da.Fill(ds, "Info");
                view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                listBox1.ItemsSource = view;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 




            }}

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {

                view.RowFilter = string.Format("Name Like '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

        }







    }
}




<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="490">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="18,77,0,83" Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="213" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"> </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>



            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="18,40,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="213" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="0,77,42,83" Name="textBlock1" Width="185" Background="#FFE6C6C6" /><Label Height="28"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,39,76,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140">Label</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```