# How does wpf/databinding resolve this ambiguity?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource Employees1}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Count}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How does the binding for the labels get resolved? How is it decided that the content of the second label is bound to Employees1.Count (and not to Employee.Count), while the first label is bound to
Employee.Name and synchonized with the listbox selection? Also, what if I would like to bind the first label to Employee.Count instead?

(Employee has properties Name (and possibly Count), Employees1 is an ObservableCollection of type Employee).

---

EDIT: So, the question here is *WHY* the first label displays the number of employees in the ObservableCollection, while the second label displays the name of a *specific* employee in the collection, the one that is currently selected in the ListBox. Apparently, the first label binds to the entire collection, and the second label to a specific employee in the collection. But why, and how to control this behavior.

Comment: Both labels are contained in the StackPanel will inherit the DataContext from the StackPanel.   It does not make sense for Name to be used by both the ListBox and Label as ListBox is a repeater control that binds to a collection and the Label does not bind to a collection.

Comment: To be honest, this is not production code with a specific purpose. I have a question about why this does what it does. I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN [Data Binding Overview, Binding To Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections), section "Current Item Pointer":

> Because WPF binds to a collection only by using a view (either a view
>   you specify, or the collection's default view), all bindings to
>   collections have a current item pointer.

and section "Master-Detail Binding Scenario":

> This works because when a singleton object (the ContentControl in this
>   case) is bound to a collection view, it automatically binds to the
>   CurrentItem of the view.

In your example, the second Label *automatically* binds to the current item of the default view of the Employees1 collection. The first Label would also bind like this, but since the item object does not have a `Count` property it apparently falls back to a binding to the `Count` property of the collection itself. However i don't know if the latter behaviour is documented somewhere.

Comment: Helpful +1. However, the second label binds to the "Count" property of the _Collection_ by default, even if Employee defines a Count property. I would really be interested in finding some documentation of this behavior. I found that I can force the binding to the employee Count property by setting : <Label Content="{Binding Path=/Count}"/> (note the slash)

Comment: Ok, then binding to the collection seems to take precedence over automatic binding to the current item. Makes sense, i guess, since you can always explicitly bind to the current item by using the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

As Blam says - the labels have no relationship to the listbox - I think what you're trying to do here is bind an observableCollection of Employees with properties Count and Name to the listbox..

To do this you'll need an ItemsTemplate in the listbox

```
<ListBox ItemSource={Binding Employees1}>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding Count}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />

    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to do that. I'm not trying to do anything, actually, I was just wondering why this does what it does.

Comment: Ok - the xaml in your question is part of the wpf visual tree and child elements will inherit their parent data context unless specifically told otherwise. So Count will evaluate the Count property of the ObservableCollection automatically. And Name will try to find the child property of the Employees1 collection. If it finds a match in the visual tree it will display if not then the value will be null. Does that help? However, again I stress that I don't think the xaml you've posted is correct for the situation you describe.

Comment: @TheUnculledBadger "If it finds a match in the visual tree ..." is not true. Binding source lookup does not traverse the visual tree (neither the logical tree). The exact behaviour is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and answer the questions.

An ObservableCollection has a property Count.

As for getting a single property on the second label it is making some assumptions.
You might not get the same behavior in other version of .NET.
Should not bind a control that displays a single value to a collection.

If you want the selected item from the ListBox see this link

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289908/listbox-selected-tem)